# Log out doesn't work in Spring Boot application (POST method not supported)

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a Spring Boot application with the following configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
open class WebSecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    override fun configure(http:HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**")
                .permitAll().and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .logout() 
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login") 
                .permitAll()
            .and().csrf().disable()
    }
    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(auth:AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("usr@provider.com").password("test").roles("USER")
    }
}
```

When I try to log out, I get the error

> There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
>   Request method 'POST' not supported

How can I fix it?

**How to reproduce**

1. Check out the code from [this repository](https://github.com/dpisarenko/spring-boot-logout).
2. `gradle bootRun`
3. Go to `http://localhost:8080`, enter `usr@provider.com` and `test` as user name and password, respectively.
4. Press the logout button.

**Update 1:** This doesn't work, either.

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/logout‌​")
        .permitAll().and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .csrf().disable()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Thymeleaf, but at least this will give you some idea.

The problem is not your SecurityConfig but the

> th:action="@{/logout}"

(not redirect to /logout, check Network tab in Chrome or Firefox).

If I replace it with

> action="/logout"

Then it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the logout path?

```
.logout() 
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
    .permitAll()
```

Comment: When I add `import org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher` to the file, the compiler say it can't resolve the referece.

Comment: sorry, try `.logoutUrl("/logout")` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can add `"/logout"` to the first section of allowed paths.

But why do you use a  with a  for the logout at all? You can use a simple link () that will issue a GET request.

Comment: I tried your approach, see "Update 1". Is that what you've meant?